# How to upgrade nativescript angular dependencies with the "tns update"?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to upgrade my @angular dependencies in my `package.json` file.

I guess the documentation
http://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions show some way to do it with : `tns update`. I upgraded my cli to `2.4` but `upgrade` doesnt work!!

i called `tns --help` and there is no appearance of `update`.

How can i update/upgrade the `@angular dependencies` into package.json file?

Comment: I see update in the third table. of tns --help. maybe tns update <platform>??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify Package.json to include most latest version of dependency by prefixing symbol ^ to existing version number.Then delete all npm dependency from npm modules folder .Remove and add platform using cli commands

```
'tns platform remove android 
 tns platfrom add android '
```

it will download new packages from npm .But its better to go with default unless cli is updataed.

Answer (score 2):

The @angular dependencies will not be updated from `tns update`.
The update command will update only the platform related dependencies and the reason your @angular dependencies won't be updated is because there are no guarantees that your current NativeScript CLI and runtime will work as expected with the last @angular updates.